# ImportError: TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard version 1.15 or above

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I follow the tutorials in [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html)
It occurs error：`TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard version 1.15 or above`,but I have install TensorBoard already.
Here is the code:

```
#from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/fashion_mnist_experiment_1')
#get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images , labels = dataiter.next()
#create grid of images
img_grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)
matplotlib_imshow(img_grid,one_channel=True)
writer.add_image('four_fashion_images',img_grid)
writer.add_graph(net, images)
writer.close()
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d38808675cb4> in <module>
----> 1 writer.add_graph(net, images)
      2 writer.close()

~\anaconda3\envs\torch2\lib\site-packages\tensorboardX\writer.py in add_graph(self, model, input_to_model, verbose)
    791 
    792         """
--> 793         from torch.utils.tensorboard._pytorch_graph import graph
    794         self._get_file_writer().add_graph(graph(model, input_to_model, verbose))
    795 

~\anaconda3\envs\torch2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      3 if not hasattr(tensorboard, '__version__') or LooseVersion(tensorboard.__version__) < LooseVersion('1.15'):
----> 4     raise ImportError('TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard version 1.15 or above')
      5 del LooseVersion
      6 del tensorboard

ImportError: TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard version 1.15 or above
```

Environment:

```
tensorboard               2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboardx              2.1                      pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.2.1                    py36_0    defaults
pytorch                   1.6.0           py3.6_cuda102_cudnn7_0    pytorch
torchvision               0.7.0                py36_cu102    pytorch
future                    0.18.2                   py36_1    defaults
protobuf                  3.12.3           py36h33f27b4_0    defaults
```

I use `from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter` at the beginning,but it occurs the error as same as above.Then I use `from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter`

Comment: I am confused. What did you exactly do to solve it? Do you know what caused your error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall `tensorflow`, `tensorboard`, `tensorboardx` and `tensorboard-plugin-wit`.

Install **only** `tensorboard` with `conda` after that.

If this doesn't work, recreate your `conda` environment only with `tensorboard`. If you need `tensorflow` as well install it beforehand.

**EDIT:**

`tensorboard-plugin-wit` is a dependency of `tensorboard` and should be installed automatically as per their [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard-plugin-wit/) description when installing `tensorboard` itself.

Comment: I recreate my conda environment with pytorch1.6 and tensorboard.When I install tensorboard,the tensorboard-plugin-wit will be installed automatically.For the [from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter],it occurs the error ImportError: TensorBoard logging requires TensorBoard version 1.15 or above

Comment: The bug confuses me for days.

Comment: @zhan could you install `pip` within conda and install [this package](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard) afterwards? I assume you are installing `<1.15.0`, this might help. Remember to pin version via `pip install tensorboard==2.3.0`.

Comment: I do as you say. It occurs the error. I use `conda list` to see the version of `tensorboard` which is 2.3.0.

Comment: I use `from tensorboard import version print(version.VERSION)` , it print `1.14.0a20190301` .But the version of the tensorboard i install is 2.3.0.

Comment: The `1.14.0a20190301` is the version of `tb-nightly`.I uninstall `tb-nightly`, It works. But I don't remember l have installed `tb-nightly` before.

Comment: I don't understand, what is causing this issue?

Comment: btw `tensorboard-plugin-wit` installs itself...I can't not have it not install itself.

Comment: @CharlieParker IIRC this happens if you install old `tensorboardX` that PyTorch is not using anymore (as it directly relies on `tensorboard`). Do you have `tensorboardX`?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I do not have `tensorboardX`. I have `tensorboard               2.4.0              pyhc547734_0  
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
` from doing your suggestion. It's really strange.

Comment: Yeah, `tensorboard-plugin-wit` is apparently dependency of `tensorboard` (check out their [pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard-plugin-wit/)), so should be fine. Is it not?

Comment: though it does import if I go to the terminal ```$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:53:00) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

>>> 
```...it's somehow if I do it from my project it doesn't work  https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils/blob/master/ultimate-utils-project/uutils/torch/distributed.py it's a single completely self contained example that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure you are the same environments in both cases, if you do, it is likely not related to `tensorboard` dependency (probably new stackoverflow question should be posted).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230515/discussion-between-charlie-parker-and-szymon-maszke).

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my directory I was working in was named `tensorboard`, so it tried to import from the current directory instead of from the installed package.
So I suggest trying to rename the directory to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
conda uninstall tensorflow
conda uninstall tensorboard
conda uninstall tensorboardx
conda uninstall tensorboard-plugin-wit
conda uninstall cloud-tpu-client
```

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorboard
pip uninstall tensorboardx
pip uninstall tensorboard-plugin-wit
pip uninstall cloud-tpu-client
```

then

```
conda install tensorboard
```

Answer (score 0):

I both tried `conda install` and `pip install`, but this error still occurred when I used `from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter` in an ipynb file. And I checked `not hasattr(tensorboard, '__version__') or LooseVersion(tensorboard.__version__) < LooseVersion('1.15')`, which both are False, meaning that it won't raise an error.

At last, I closed this ipynb file and restarted it, it worked. You should try this and no need to be struggling in reinstalling your conda env.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I had only Tensorboard without Tensorflow when I faced the error, so I had to:

`conda uninstall tensorboard` - this removed PyTorch Lightning as well
  `conda install tensorboard`
  `conda install -c conda-forge pytorch-lightning`